# how to reduce size of main.js after production build and reduce size of asset folder

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, production

I want reduce my project size. I successfully tried **ng build --prod** command, but after that my **main.js** file size is 2 Mb. so i want to reduce that size. also i want to compress asset folder.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be such a big deal since that's the size before compression. When you serve your content to users, it's usually through a web server (NGIX/ IIS), which means they use Brotli or Gzip. Your JS file size will be (usually) reduced to less than a quarter (< 500KB), and less than 1/9 for CSS.

If you want to reduce your actual size, consider analyzing it first, with tools like [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) for switching/replacing appropriate packages